# c program for user to input two type of number and give output how many number user input

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

User need to input 2 type of input 3 times, which is number 1 for pass and number 2 for fail...program need to give the summary of how many user input number 1 and number 2

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int result[3];
    int pass;
    int fail;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        printf("Enter Result (Pass=1 Fail=2) :");
        scanf("%d", &result[i]);
    }
    if (&result == 1) {
        pass = pass + 1;
    }
    if (&result == 2) {
        fail = fail + 1;
    }
    printf("%d", pass);
    printf("%d", fail);
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you struggling with? Please show your code.

Comment: based on my code, how can i get the result of how many pass and fail ?

Comment: What do you think `&result == 1` does? Also, arrays are zero-based in C. You are only allowed to access `result[0]`, `result[1]` and `result[2]`.

Comment: how can i take &result input value and differentiate as pass or fail variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- `&result == 1` takes the address of the array `result` and tries to compare that to the integer `1`. This will, if the code even compiles, very rarely be true. You want to compare `result[index]` with `1` (or `2`).
- You read all the inputs in a loop, but you only make the comparison once after the loop.
- Arrays are zero-based. Since `result` is an `int[3]`, you are only allowed to access `result[0]`, `result[1]` and `result[2]`.
- Both `pass` and `fail` are uninitialized and contains indeterminate values. Reading those, which is required in `pass = pass + 1;`, will make the program have undefined behavior. Initialize them to `0`.

I suggest not using an array and then do the comparisons with `1` and `2` inside the loop.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int result;
    int pass = 0;
    int fail = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Enter Result (Pass=1 Fail=2) :");

        if (scanf("%d", &result) != 1) {
            fputs("Erroneous input\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        if (result == 1) {
            pass = pass + 1;
        } else if (result == 2) {
            fail = fail + 1;
        } else {
            printf("The invalid input %d will not be counted\n", result);
        }
    }

    printf("pass: %d\n", pass);
    printf("fail: %d\n", fail);
}
```

Comment: @Cadefr6554 You're welcome! Glad it helped!